# want to pass the item id in place of item name

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

I want to get the itemid to pass..But I'm using autocomplete it returns the name of selected item..How to retrieve the item id as value??
Here is my code,

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value1: ''
          }
```

.........................................................................................................................................

```
<ReactAutocomplete
                                name="ReferredBy"
                                items = {patientsMasterData.ReferredBy && patientsMasterData.ReferredBy.map(referredObj =>(
                                    {options:referredObj.RefName, 
                                    values:referredObj.RefID}
                                    ))
                                }
                                shouldItemRender={(item, value1) => item.options.toLowerCase().indexOf(value1.toLowerCase()) > -1}
                                getItemValue={(item) => item.options}
                                renderItem={(item, highlighted) =>
                                    <div
                                    key={item.values}

                                    style={{ backgroundColor: highlighted ? '#3db4e5' : '#FFFFFF',cursor:'pointer', border:'1px solid lighten($grey-element,30%)',padding: '5px' }}
                                    >
                                    {item.options}
                                    </div>
                                }
                                inputProps={{placeholder:'Select...'}}
                                menuStyle={this.props.menuStyle}
                                wrapperStyle={this.props.wrapperStyle}
                                value={this.state.value1}
                                onChange={e => this.setState({ value1:(e.target.value) })}
                                onSelect={value1 => this.setState({ value1 })}
                    />
```

I tried so many ways but no output.. It be great helpful to anyone solve this problem.

Comment: change getItemValue function it is returning options change it to values, since it is pointing to refId

Comment: ya I tried that... but this `react-dom.development.js?61bb:16543 Uncaught TypeError: value1.toLowerCase is not a function` error shown

Comment: check the type of value1, if it is similar to {options:'something', values:'something' } then extract the value. Just log it to console once and see it's type. then it should be simple to solve the issue

Comment: options:'name' and values:'id(number)'

Comment: shouldItemRender={(item, value1) => {
  const {values} = value1;
  const opt = item.options.toLowerCase();
  return opt.indexOf(values) > -1;
  }
}

Comment: the previous comment should work.

Comment: nope, now the dropdown selection list also missing... :(

Comment: can u make a codesandbox. It would be better to fix then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184126/discussion-between-mily-alfrad-and-klvenky).